# Model is not found. Bug in Laravel Framework?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

**My Model is like this**

```
class redModel extends Model {

    public $table = 'tbl50red';
    public $primaryKey = 'RedID';
    public $timestamps = true;

}
```

**and here is another model**

```
class AddOnModel extends Model {

    public $table = 'tbladdon';
    public $primaryKey = 'AddOnID';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function AppRed() {
        return $this->hasMany("\App\Models\AddOn\Red\redModel", "AddOnID", "AddOnID");
    }
}
```

In the controller when i run this:

```
$AddOns = AddOnModel
    ::with(array("AppRed" => function($query) use($StartDate, $EndDate) {
        return $query->whereBetween("EarningDate", array($StartDate, $EndDate));
    }))
    ->get();
```

I get an exception :

> Class '\App\Models\AddOn\Red edModel' not found

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug in Laravel. Please read the [PSR-1 Basic Coding Standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) which will enable you to easily avoid this error in the future. Namely, this is the part you are violating:

> Class names MUST be declared in `StudlyCaps`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the given way...

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Application extends Model
{
    public function AppRed()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(redModel::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I open below file:

> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php

and checked this function

```
public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
{
    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
    $instance = new $related;

    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

    return new HasMany($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
}
```

I saw I was not able to instantiate the model because model name was starting with r . lol

and i was pulling my hair since morning and another coincident was that it was like this \r so it was missing the model name and I think replacing \r with blank space and due to that the url was becoming like this

```
\App\Models\AddOn\Red edModel
```

and actual was this

```
\App\Models\AddOn\Red\redModel
```

I think it's a bug in Laravel framework.

Answer (score 0):

Change `"\App\Models\AddOn\Red\redModel"` to:

`"\App\Models\AddOn\Red\\redModel"`

i.e. the extra `\` will escape the `\r`. `\r` is a control character, which is why you're getting an issue.